# Summing Conditionally Formatted Range: VBA code giving me #VALUE error in a cell, even though the code compiles and it evaluates correctly?

Tags: vba

I am dealing with a range of cells that have conditional formatting rules embedded in them.  I only want to sum the cells that are expressing the conditional formatting (in this case, the cells highlighted green, or highlighted with color index = 15).

This is a template, so the cells that are highlighted version to version will change.

The code I've written so far compiles without issue, and evaluates the result correctly, but when I run the function ("sumPercentages") in the cell beneath the range, it returns "#VALUE!"  What am I missing?

```
Option Explicit

Function sumPercentages(R1 As Range) As Double
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim rowCount As Integer
   Dim rCell As Range
   Dim lCol As Long

   For Each rCell In R1
       If rCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
           sumPercentages = sumPercentages + rCell.Value
       Else
       End If
   Next rCell
End Function
```

Comment: `DisplayFormat` doesn't work in UDFs in a worksheet (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat). Usually better to use the CF criteria.

Comment: @SJR.  Thanks for the response.  I'll keep looking for a workaround.